# After creating a new email with Adobe Acrobat I cannot run VBA for that email

Tags: vba, outlook, adobe, acrobat

I have created a macro in Outlook 2013 (32 bits) that it is supposed to get the name of an attachment and set the subject the same as the filename of an attachment and it works perfect if the email is created from any other app or even inside of Outlook, except when the email is created from Adobe Acrobat.

If you open a file in Adobe Acrobat and want to send it by email and click on the icon "Send file as email attachment" in Adobe Acrobat, it will open a new email in Outlook 2013 and also, it will attach the file to that new email, but after this step, I want to run my macro and I am not able to run it.

Do I need to set up something special in Adobe? I have read several websites with technical support and I cannot find the answer. I have more than 15 days looking for information and I haven't been able to find it.

I am using Adobe Acrobat XI Standard and Office 2013 (32 bits)

Even a macro in VBA like:

```
Public Sub HelloWorld()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

won't work if the email was created through Adobe Acrobat.

Edit:

Code for Set the subject of an email the same as the attachment.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertText()
    Dim attachment As attachment
    Dim report As String
    Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    If oInspector Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No active inspector. Please, talk to your IT Department."
    Else
        Set newMail = oInspector.currentItem
            If newMail.Sent Then
                MsgBox "This is not an editable email"
            Else
                For Each attachment In newMail.Attachments
                    report = report & attachment.FileName & "; "
                Next
                newMail.Subject = report
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please provide the macro you say is working fine? And also describe how the macro gets triggered.

Comment: This was solved with an update from Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the macro gets triggered by pressing a button I created in the Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

A sample macro shouldn't be run automatically when a new MailItem is opened. Instead, you need to handle Outlook events.

The Outlook object model provides the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program. You can use it for making changes after a user submitted the mail item for sending.

Also you may find the [NewInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Inspectors class helpful. It is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code.

Finally, I'd recommend starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Simple MAPI not Outlook.

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/203

"When I start creating an email from another application, I cannot access Outlook anymore.

You’ll find this behavior when you for instance use Send-> Email in Word or Excel (or any other Office application) or when choosing Sent To-> Mail Recipient when right clicking a file in Explorer.

This is because the Send To command initiates Simple MAPI which only loads a stub of Outlook and launches a modal form instead of a modeless form. This means that the form must be completed before the application underneath the form can be used again.

There is no direct workaround for this other than to start creating a mail from within Outlook instead of another application."

Comment: Hi.Thanks for that explanation, and I understand I am using a Simple MAPI. But this behaviour is pretty new since the macro works perfect with Adobe Acrobat 9.5 and Outlook 2010 and any other application. The problem comes with Adobe Acrobat XI and Outlook 2013 (32 bits). So I would like to know if there is a way to set up that MAPI in 2013 as the same macro works perfect for previous versions. I'll post the macro in next comment

Comment: The following Macro in Outlook, goes in a module. I already added a button in Message Ribbon (it appears after you creates a new email), and that button execute the macro. I don't want to create an event as I don't want to run this macro for every single email I send. I just set the subject the same as the name of the attachment when I consider necessary. This happens several times in a day but it is not for all the emails I sent. That's the reason I would like to keep it as Macro in a module. Here the macro:

Answer (score 0):

Code for Set the subject of an email the same as the attachment:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertText()
    Dim attachment As attachment
    Dim report As String
    Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    If oInspector Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No active inspector. Please, talk to your IT Department."
    Else
        Set newMail = oInspector.currentItem
            If newMail.Sent Then
                MsgBox "This is not an editable email"
            Else
                For Each attachment In newMail.Attachments
                    report = report & attachment.FileName & "; "
                Next
                newMail.Subject = report
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As I said, It will work perfect when you create a new email from outlook, add an attachment and then run the macro. It will also work "beautifully" if you create an email from Adobe Acrobat 9.5 and you have Outlook 2010. But I am trying to see if I can enable "something" like MAPI or anything else to make Outlook 2013 accept to create the email from Adobe, so I can run the macro. Actually, if you create a new email from Adobe Acrobat XI, it won't let you touch any other button from Outlook until you send the email, or you save the email as draft and, close the that active window and open it

Comment: again. If you know anything I have to set up, or enable, please, let me know.